# Infestation Containment

Tags: rimworld

I ran into my first infestation last night. Now all but two of my colonists are downed. Those two are hiding in their bedrooms as everyone else bleeds out. This has raised a few questions about my new visitors that I haven't been able to find the answers to.

It sounds like if I had left them closed up in the storage room they appeared in, they would have left me alone. But now that they're out, can the be re-contained? They are currently closed out of the room with the hives. Will they attack the walls or door to get back in there? If I open it up for them, will they go back in? If they do, can I shut them in, or are they "triggered" now (break out to attack me some more)?

They have already attacked the windmill and solar cells that they could get to without opening doors. Will they attack other things? Will they break down doors or walls to get to stuff?

I understand they sleep at some point. Do they follow the usual day/night cycle? Is it safe to try rescuing people at that point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Bugs will actively try to attack you if you get too close. Even if
   there's a wall in between they sometimes will try tunneling towards
   you.
2. If you attack the hives they will try to get back to the hives to defend them.
3. Yes, they might at some point try to attack more things, although if it's far away from them they might just be content to wonder around.
4. Yes they sleep, usually during the regular day night cycle. It's safe to approach them and rescue colonists, as long as you don't walk into a tile next to them.

It's also safe to build a wall around them, fill the space they are
inside with wooden floors and wooden chairs, add a few incendiary traps
and then watch the chaos unfold once they wake up.

Be careful though, bugs will tunnel trough two doors to get away from fire before the succumb to the heat, make sure there's lots of layers so they can't get away once the fire start.

Comment: I would like to emphasize that a furnace room (lots of wooden things and floors plus incendiary/molotov) is the safest way to deal with them, but be careful that the fire doesn't get out of hand or catch your base on fire too. I've lost a couple of good colonists when they started trying to fight fire and bugs at once.

Comment: Note that as more bugs emerge, they wander in a bigger radius around their nest (so as to keep bug density fairly equalised). When they wandering takes them through a wall, they will attempt to burrow through it. This means that infestations can really get out of hand in the long run.